# Why different Response HTTP headers after Tibco BW migration from 5.13 to 5.5

Tags: http, tomcat7, tomcat9, tibco-business-works

We have migrated from Tibco BW 5.13 to Tibco BW 5.15.
We have a simple process with 3 steps. HTTP Receiver > Send HTTP Response > End.

After running this in BW 5.13, we get below HTTP Headers in response,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 614
Date: Fri, 28 Jul 2023 14:39:07 GMT
```

However, if we migrate and run same code in 5.15, we get different HTTP Headers in response,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 614
Date: Fri, 28 Jul 2023 14:40:21 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=2000
Connection: keep-alive
```

Kindly help me with an explanation to this difference in behavior.

Comment: 5.13 and 5.15 most likely using different versions of commons-httpclient.jar